# Extract information using NLP and store it in csv file

Tags: text-mining, data-science-model, feature-extraction, nlp

I have a text file that stores the pickup, drops, and time. SMS text is a dummy file that is used to train a cab service model. The text is like in this format:

```
Please book a cab from airport to hauz khaas at 3 PM
airport to hauz khaas at 6 PM
Kindly book a cab for me at 1 PM from hauz khaas to dwarka sector 23
airport to hauz khaas at 1 AM
I want to go to dwarka sector 21 from airport leaving at 10 PM
airport to dwarka sector 21 at 12 PM
Please book a cab for dwarka sector 23 from hauz khaas at 12 PM
Please book a cab from dwarka sector 23 to dwarka sector 21 at 4 PM
```

The problem is I need to create 3 columns in a csv file - Destination, Pickup and Time. I used almost every technique but It is not accurately extracting the text. I tried chinking, POS tagging, regex I also tried `LatentDirichletAllocation` to create the features but need some help to understand what is missing. 
Here is the code that I used:

```
import nltk
returnme = list()
def process_content():
    try:
        returnme1 = list()
        for i in txtData.splitlines()[0:4]:
            list1 = set()
            words = nltk.ngrams(i.split(), 2)

            for j in words:
              pos = nltk.pos_tag(j)
              grm = r"""origin:{(<NN><TO>)|(<NN><VBG>)|(<VB><NN><TO>)}
              time:{(<CD><NN> ) | (<CD><NNS>)}
              dest: {(<VB><NN><CD>) | (<VB><NN>)}
              All:{(<IN><NN>)|<CD>|<NN>|<TO><NN>|<NN><NN><CD>} """
              chunkword = nltk.RegexpParser(grm)
              chuncked = chunkword.parse(pos)
              subtreelst = set()
              for subtree in chuncked.subtrees():                           
                if (subtree.label() == 'origin' and subtree.label() != 'S'):
                    subtreelst.add('origin: '+subtree.leaves()[0][0])
                if (subtree.label() == 'time' and subtree.label() != 'S'):
                    subtreelst.add('time: '+subtree.leaves()[0][0])
                if (subtree.label() == 'dest' and subtree.label() != 'S'):
                    subtreelst.add('dest: '+subtree.leaves()[0][0])
                if (subtree.label() == 'All' and subtree.label() != 'S'):
                   subtreelst.add('All: '+subtree.leaves()[0][0])
              list1.update(subtreelst)
            returnme.append(list1)
        returnme1.append(returnme)  


        return returnme1
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


mylst = list()
mylst.append(process_content())
mylst
```

This is giving the following output:

```
[[[{'All: 3',
    'All: book',
    'All: cab',
    'All: from',
    'All: hauz',
    'All: khaas',
    'origin: airport',
    'time: 3'},
   {'All: 6', 'All: hauz', 'All: khaas', 'origin: airport', 'time: 6'},
   {'All: 1',
    'All: 23',
    'All: PM',
    'All: book',
    'All: cab',
    'All: dwarka',
    'All: from',
    'All: hauz',
    'All: khaas',
    'All: sector',
    'origin: khaas',
    'time: 1'},
   {'All: 1', 'All: hauz', 'All: khaas', 'origin: airport'}]]]
```

LatentDirichletAllocation Part:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import nltk
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
    from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    import re
    All_Reviews = pd.DataFrame(txtData.splitlines())
    def remove_non_alphabets(text):
        non_valid_word = re.compile(r'[-.?!,:;()"--``\[\]\|]')
        token = word_tokenize(text)
        return_me = list()
        for w in token:
            word= non_valid_word.sub("",w)
            word= re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', word, flags=re.MULTILINE) # removed URLs
            word= re.sub(" \d+", " ", word) # remove digits 
            #word = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', "", word)
            #word = re.sub(r'\[\[(?:[^\]|]*\|)?([^\]|]*)\]\]', r'\1', line)
            return_me.append(word)
        return return_me

    def dostopwords(text):
        return_me = " ".join([c for c in text if c not in stopwords.words('english')])
        return return_me    
    #     return_me = list()
    #        # token = word_tokenize(text)
    #     for w in text:
    #         if w not in stopwords.words('english'):
    #             return_me.append(w)
    #     return return_me

    def counter(text):    
        fdist = FreqDist()
        for f in text:
            fdist[f.lower()] +=1
        return fdist
All_Reviews[0]= All_Reviews[0].apply(lambda lb: remove_non_alphabets(lb))
All_Reviews[0] = All_Reviews[0].apply(lambda lb: dostopwords(lb))
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
CV = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,max_features=1000,ngram_range = (1,3),stop_words='english')
vect = CV.fit_transform(All_Reviews[0])
header = CV.get_feature_names()
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=5)
lda_output = lda.fit_transform(vect)
sorting = np.argsort(lda.components_)[:,::-1] 
features = np.array(CV.get_feature_names()) 
features
```

The output is:

```
array(['10', '10 airport', '10 dwarka', '10 dwarka sector', '10 pm',
       '10 pm dwarka', '10 pm hauz', '11', '11 dwarka',
       '11 dwarka sector', '11 pm', '11 pm airport', '11 pm hauz', '12',
       '12 dwarka', '12 dwarka sector', '12 hauz', '12 hauz khaas',
       '12 pm', '12 pm airport', '12 pm dwarka', '12 pm hauz', '21',
       '21 10', '21 10 pm', '21 11', '21 11 pm', '21 12', '21 12 pm',
       '21 airport', '21 airport 10', '21 airport 11', '21 airport 12',
       '21 airport leaving', '21 airport pm', '21 dwarka',
       '21 dwarka sector', '21 hauz', '21 hauz khaas', '21 leaving',
       '21 leaving 10', '21 leaving 11', '21 leaving 12', '21 leaving pm',
       '21 pm', '23', '23 10', '23 10 pm', '23 11', '23 11 pm', '23 12',
       '23 12 pm', '23 airport', '23 airport 10', '23 airport 11',
       '23 airport 12', '23 airport leaving', '23 airport pm',
       '23 dwarka', '23 dwarka sector', '23 hauz', '23 hauz khaas',
       '23 leaving', '23 leaving 10', '23 leaving 11', '23 leaving pm',
       '23 pm', 'airport', 'airport 10', 'airport 10 pm', 'airport 11',
       'airport 11 pm', 'airport 12', 'airport 12 pm', 'airport dwarka',
       'airport dwarka sector', 'airport hauz', 'airport hauz khaas',
       'airport leaving', 'airport leaving 10', 'airport leaving 12',
       'airport leaving pm', 'airport pm', 'book', 'book cab',
       'book cab 10', 'book cab 11', 'book cab 12', 'book cab airport',
       'book cab dwarka', 'book cab hauz', 'book cab pm', 'cab', 'cab 10',
       'cab 10 airport', 'cab 10 dwarka', 'cab 10 pm', 'cab 11',
       'cab 11 dwarka', 'cab 11 pm', 'cab 12', 'cab 12 dwarka',
       'cab 12 hauz', 'cab 12 pm', 'cab airport', 'cab airport dwarka',
       'cab airport hauz', 'cab dwarka', 'cab dwarka sector', 'cab hauz',
       'cab hauz khaas', 'cab pm', 'cab pm airport', 'cab pm dwarka',
       'cab pm hauz', 'dwarka', 'dwarka sector', 'dwarka sector 21',
       'dwarka sector 23', 'hauz', 'hauz khaas', 'hauz khaas 10',
       'hauz khaas 11', 'hauz khaas 12', 'hauz khaas airport',
       'hauz khaas dwarka', 'hauz khaas leaving', 'hauz khaas pm',
       'khaas', 'khaas 10', 'khaas 10 pm', 'khaas 11', 'khaas 11 pm',
       'khaas 12', 'khaas 12 pm', 'khaas airport', 'khaas airport 10',
       'khaas airport 11', 'khaas airport 12', 'khaas airport leaving',
       'khaas airport pm', 'khaas dwarka', 'khaas dwarka sector',
       'khaas leaving', 'khaas leaving 10', 'khaas leaving 11',
       'khaas leaving 12', 'khaas leaving pm', 'khaas pm', 'kindly',
       'kindly book', 'kindly book cab', 'leaving', 'leaving 10',
       'leaving 10 pm', 'leaving 11', 'leaving 11 pm', 'leaving 12',
       'leaving 12 pm', 'leaving pm', 'pm', 'pm airport',
       'pm airport dwarka', 'pm airport hauz', 'pm dwarka',
       'pm dwarka sector', 'pm hauz', 'pm hauz khaas', 'sector',
       'sector 21', 'sector 21 10', 'sector 21 11', 'sector 21 12',
       'sector 21 airport', 'sector 21 dwarka', 'sector 21 hauz',
       'sector 21 leaving', 'sector 21 pm', 'sector 23', 'sector 23 10',
       'sector 23 11', 'sector 23 12', 'sector 23 airport',
       'sector 23 dwarka', 'sector 23 hauz', 'sector 23 leaving',
       'sector 23 pm', 'want', 'want airport', 'want airport dwarka',
       'want airport hauz', 'want book', 'want book cab', 'want dwarka',
       'want dwarka sector', 'want hauz', 'want hauz khaas'], dtype='<U21')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you try everything but didn't design the system so that it does what you need it to do. In this task I don't see any reason to use things like LDA for instance. In my opinion this is a typical case for training a custom NE system which extracts specifically the targets you want. The first step is to annotate a subset of your data, for example like this:

```
Please   _
book     _
a        _
cab      _
from     _
airport  FROM_B
to       _
hauz     TO_B
khaas    TO_I
at       _
3        TIME_B
PM       TIME_I
```

A NE model is trained from such annotated data. Here I proposed an option with labels by category plus B for Begin, I for Inside, but there can be many variants.

Once the model is trained, applying to any unlabelled text should directly give you the target information.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Erwan you have to build named entity recognition model which will do your task easily. For understanding implementation of ner task you can refer to my notebook on kaggle which is based on similar dataset of flight rather cab. So it will help to custom build the dataset & upto certain extend use the prediction of my model.

[Kaggle Notebook Link](https://www.kaggle.com/swapnilpote/flight-named-entity-recognition/notebook)

```
['BOS', 'Please', 'book', 'a', 'flight', 'from', 'dwarka', 'sector', '23', 'from', 'hauz', 'khaas', 'at', '12', 'PM', 'EOS']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-depart_time.time', 'I-depart_time.time', 'O']
```